# install4j application name in Gnome 3

Tags: java, install4j

When our application is installed by install4j on a Gnome 3 desktop in Linux, and the application runs: the Application menu, located beside the Activities button which shows the name of the active application is showing "com-install4j-runtime-launcher-UnixLauncher".

Is there a setting in install4j so that our application name shows up properly instead?

Answer (score 1):

As of install4j 7, there is only a hack to achieve this:

Define the compiler variable

```
sys.ext.windowClass.<nn>=MyAppName
```

where `<nn>` is the ID of the launcher and `MyAppName` must not contain spaces.

This will add a "StartupWMClass" entry to the `.desktop` file.

For the AWT, the actual window class has to be set to the same value programmatically. This is not possible with an API, but just by using reflection:

```
String wmClass = ...;
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Class<?> toolkitClass = toolkit.getClass();

if (Objects.equals("sun.awt.X11.XToolkit", toolkitClass.getName())) {
    //noinspection JavaReflectionMemberAccess
    Field awtAppClassName = toolkitClass.getDeclaredField("awtAppClassName");
    awtAppClassName.setAccessible(true);
    awtAppClassName.set(null, wmClass);
}
```

Comment: We did this and then ran in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it had no effect.

Comment: Can you locate the ".desktop" file that is used for starting the application and check if it has a "StartupWMClass" entry? That is the effect of the compiler variable.

Comment: I think `ReflectionUtil.setAccessible(awtAppClassName);` should be `awtAppClassName.setAccessible(true)`, right?

Comment: Correct, I changed it.