# Override install4j UnixLauncher WM_CLASS property

Tags: java, linux, deployment, install4j

Is it possible to override the `WM_CLASS` set by install4j on Linux environments?

At the moment, executing

```
xprop WM_CLASS
```

on my application deployed with install4j always returns `com-install4j-runtime-launcher-UnixLauncher`.
This is a problem when creating proper .desktop files, I do not want to group together all applications deployed with install4j.

I gather [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117380/install4j-application-name-in-gnome-3?rq=1) deals with a similar problem. However, the answer does not work for me. The mentioned `sys.ext.windowClass` compiler variable is not documented anywhere I can find and as far as I can see it does nothing.

Comment: Please see the referenced question again, the answer was incomplete and I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, window managers group windows and assign the correct icons by using the `WM_CLASS` property.

This property can be inspected using *xprop*:

```
xprop WM_CLASS
```

To specify which WM_CLASS a .desktop file should affect, you can use the `StartupWMClass` property in a desktop file:

```
StartupWMClass=<my-applications-wm-class>
```

The problem with install4j is that all deployed applications will use 
`com-install4j-runtime-launcher-UnixLauncher` as WM_CLASS.

As Ingo Kegel mentions in his now edited answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117380/install4j-application-name-in-gnome-3?rq=1), this can be circumvented by setting the WM_CLASS window property explicitly in your Java application using the following code:

```java
String wmClass = ...;
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Class<?> toolkitClass = toolkit.getClass();

if (Objects.equals("sun.awt.X11.XToolkit", toolkitClass.getName())) {

    Field awtAppClassName = toolkitClass.getDeclaredField("awtAppClassName");
    awtAppClassName.setAccessible(true);
    awtAppClassName.set(null, wmClass);
}
```

If you have preliminary dialogs when your application starts (e.g. for selecting a workspace), it is important that you do this for all dialogs separately.